# BackupExec - write a yearly backup to multiple tapes in a library?

Tags: backup, backupexec, symantec, veritas

I have BackupExec 12.5.  I have about 25 servers that need to be backed up to tape.  I already have the tape library "partitioned" into the 12 tape slots for normal backups, so it isn't just a single large partition.

I'd like to backup these 25 servers as a single backup job and have the backup job just grab the first slot and so on until finished.  If I break up the job there will be a lot of "wasted tape".  The slots have blank tapes in them.

If I select "All Devices" in the backup job destination will that suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a 12 slot Auto-loader? In that case I would target the job at the parent device for the Auto-loader instead of All Devices. If you have any B2D folders and you target All Devices, the job may write to the B2D folders instead of the tapes.

Comment: ah...ok I was wondering that.  It's exactly as you say.  So I'll choose "ArcVault12" instead.  If I run a test job and it succeeds I would assume I'm good to go?

Comment: I would think so, yes.

Comment: That worked well choosing the actual device.  It started with slot 1 and worked its way down.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

I would create a media set such as Year End or whatever and add the tapes you want available to that set. In the job, use the newly created set as the target.  The autoloader should just keep picking tapes as needed.